# How to deal with "negligible" coefficients from averaged linear regression?

Tags: regression, mean, model, linear

I have an apparently simple (and maybe stupid) question.
I have a data set `dT` with 168 subjects.  I ran a linear regression in `R` to give the model `m1` assessing the relationship between response "Age" and a set of seven chosen factor variables. I also included three two-way interactions between some of those variables.

```
m1 <- lm(var ~
           Sex +            # 2 levels
           Trauma +         # 2 levels
           Type +           # 3 levels
           DelLigLesion +   # 2 levels
           SprLigLesion +   # 2 levels
           SprLigLocation + # 2 levels
           TPTLesion +      # 4 levels
           Type:Trauma +
           Sex:Type +
           Trauma:Sex,
         data = dT, na.action = na.fail)
```

Then I generated a model selection table with all combinations of effects using [`dredge`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.43.17/topics/dredge) (default settings) and averaged (full) over the subset with `deltaAIC < 2`, which gives me a subset of 6 models.

```
dm <- dredge(m1)
print(dm)

Model selection table 
     (Int) DLL Sex SprLgLs SprLgLc TPT Trm Typ Sex:Trm Sex:Typ Trm:Typ df   logLik   AICc delta weight
125  36.10               +       +   +   +   +                          9 -825.782 1670.5  0.00  0.074
383  38.75       +       +       +   +   +   +               +         12 -822.650 1671.0  0.47  0.059
379  39.22       +               +   +   +   +               +         11 -824.108 1671.6  1.11  0.042
121  36.52                       +   +   +   +                          8 -827.446 1671.7  1.13  0.042
126  36.84   +           +       +   +   +   +                         10 -825.414 1672.0  1.48  0.035
384  39.57   +   +       +       +   +   +   +               +         13 -822.247 1672.5  1.95  0.028

m2 <- model.avg(get.models(dm, subset=delta<2))
```

The coefficient and 95% CI output looks like this:

```
cbind(coefTable(m2, full=T),confint(m2, full=T))

                             Estimate Std. Error df      2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)                37.6284217   9.239456 NA  19.519420 55.737424
SprLigLesionComplete        2.8663869   2.745389 NA  -2.514476  8.247250
SprLigLocationIntermedial -13.5599463   6.371489 NA -26.047835 -1.072058
TPTLesionPartial           10.7908223   4.193205 NA   2.572292 19.009353
TPTLesionDistal            21.5392665   8.805364 NA   4.281070 38.797463
TPTLesionDistal+Bone        3.8884638   9.610411 NA -14.947595 22.724523
TraumaYes                  -6.4792438   2.576627 NA -11.529340 -1.429147
Type3A                     25.0419915  10.706594 NA   4.057453 46.026530
Type3B                      0.0000000   0.000000 NA   0.000000  0.000000
SexM                        4.0068936   5.532559 NA  -6.836722 14.850509
SexM:Type3A                -3.3116556   5.604008 NA -14.295310  7.671999
SexM:Type3B                -7.1260396   8.862440 NA -24.496103 10.244023
DelLigLesionYes            -0.5295235   1.640540 NA  -3.744922  2.685875
```

Ignoring the apparently not estimated coefficient of `Type3B`,
I am wondering how to deal with very small association such as in this case with `DelLigLesionYes` with an estimate of -0.53 years and a 95%CI of -3.74 to 2.69.
To me it seems irrelevant and of little importance to report a difference of 0.53 years especially with a 95% CI this wide.

How would more experienced modelers treat this variable/model?
Should I reduce the subset of models to average on (e.g., reducing `deltaAIC` to 1, or using BIC instead of AICc)?
Or can I just ignore this effect and not mention it in a publication?

This community has already been of incredible help to me, and I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dangerous data mining procedure that is essentially playing with the data in a way that will badly distort all aspects of statistical inference, starting with a biased (low) estimate of the residual variance.  Models need to be pre-specified from subject matter considerations, with the possible exception of a secondary model that also includes interactions (but that adjusts liberally for all main effects).  These ideas are detailed at [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Frank. Data mining is what I want to avoid, but I wanted to consider as many aspects (variables of interest) from the data as possible. I was hoping to get the associations between response and predictors in some context with the other predictors. Was I too ambigious? Should I reduce number of predictors, and run separate models to assess the relationship between response and predictors?

Comment: I'd rather see one carefully pre-specified model (or possibly two) and not "run separate models".

Comment: Obviously, the coefficients and confidence interval depend on whether we use the full average (variable is included in every model, but in some models the corresponding coefficient (and variance) is set to zero) or a conditional average (only averages over the models where the parameter appears).

Comment: Therefore, given 4 zeros in the calculation of the average coefficient and variance, the resultant coefficient is accordingly small. However, it looks more robust when I am using the conditional average: the coefficient for `DeltoidLigLesion` would then be -2.34, and the 95%CI -7.8 to 3.1.

Comment: Not sure how to know whether the statistical properties are preserved when looking at multiple models.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues here. First of all the whole point of confidence intervals (and significance testing) is to tell you whether a coefficient is significantly different from zero or not. If the confidence interval includes zero then you can't say that the coefficient is significantly different from zero at the stated confidence level. This is the whole point of significance testing: to decide when to reject the null hypothesis that the parameter in question is actually zero.

Second, your whole approach to model building here seems problematic, as another comment noted. One of the issues is that you don't want to just throw in a bunch of interaction terms in to a model without some theoretical understanding of why those interactions are potentially important. Adding interactions has implications for statistical power, makes coefficients hard to interpret, and can cause overfitting. So you really want to have a reason to include them. This is especially true when you only have 160 or so observations, which seems way too few for a model like this. As the other comment noted, specifying a "good" model is something that requires prior theory and subject matter knowledge, as well as an understanding of how decisions about what to include impact statistical inference. If you just throw a bunch of variables and interactions in the program will give you an answer but it may not mean what you think it does.

Comment: My point of using AIC was to defy significance tests for model selection in first place. But with a significant test I would be able to claim that a variable is associated with the response. But in my case the coefficient of -0.53 is relatively small (given the wide confidence interval -3.74 - 2.69). To me it seems that this variable is not really important and it makes me wonder, why it is retained in the model. But anyway, you have a good point in bringing up the overfitting issue.

Comment: AIC is just a rescaling of a statistical test, so your point is not valid.  And the idea of removing a variable from the model after the fact is just data mining / double dipping.